# Borrowing and Lifetime for Factory to Concrete Implementation

Tags: rust

I am very new to rust and currently trying out simple concepts to understand it more.  I have created a sample of a Concrete Factory taking a Trait Dependency and its `create` method returning a Concrete Instance which is defined by a trait.

I am getting errors about lifetime borrowing.

I have create a failing example in the playground here.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9753708dc202c27101442952dabf560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did most things correct, there is only one major constraint you missed: When you return your `dyn SomethingToUse` from the factory:

```rust
pub fn create(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn SomethingToUse>>{
    let something = SomethingConcrete{
        helper: self.helper // I removed the & here. That would be a double reference.
    };
    return Ok(Box::new(something));
}
```

It contains a reference  which is valid for `'a`. You however did not annotate that. The way to do that is `dyn SomethingToUse + 'a`.

I also replaced your boxed trait object with an `impl SomethingToUse` as I would prefer that in most situations, that's not necessary though.

Link to working code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b02c4ff9d5e2ad03b7dfd2db00941b7c

Comment: I thank you, for providing a link to the Rust playground. By the way, I wont search for duplicates, but I would expect there to be some, as I imagine this problem to be rather common. I however see that searching for the right question here on SO given the error message is nearly impossible for someone inexperienced with Rust.